# NullPointerException in Storm when running topology

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception, apache-storm, core.async

I am getting `NullPointerException`s in `backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor` method when running my topology, specifically in a bolt. Spouts are duly executed.

Storm's troubleshooting [page](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Troubleshooting.html) says that it might be due to multiple threads issuing methods on the OutputCollector. However, i cannot see where does it relate to my case.

Here's the code for the spout:

```
(defspout stub-spout ["stub-spout"]
  [conf context collector]
  (spout
    (nextTuple []
      (let [channel-value (<!! storm-async-channel)]
        (emit-spout! collector [channel-value])))
    (ack [id]
      ))))
```

and for the bolt:

```
(defbolt stub-bolt ["stub-bolt"] [tuple collector]
  (println "Invocation!")
  (let [obj (get tuple "object")
        do-some-calculations (resolve 'calclib/do-some-calculations)
        new-obj (do-some-calculations obj)]
    (emit-bolt! collector new-obj)))
```

After some investigation it turned out that the call to `resolve` returns null (i need to `resolve` during runtime as some calculation occurs in a macro located in `calclib`).

The code runs properly in local cluster though. Why is this happening?

Will be grateful for any suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think i've found a solution. The bolt definition is changed to a prepared bolt:

```
(defbolt stub-bolt ["stub-bolt"] 
  {:prepare true}
  [conf context collector]
  (let [f (load "/calclib/core")
        do-some-calculations (resolve 'calclib/do-some-calculations)]
    (bolt
      (execute [tuple]  
        (let [obj (get tuple "object")
              new-obj (do-some-calculations obj)]
          (emit-bolt! collector new-obj))))))
```

Key is the call to `load`. I wonder if there's a more elegant approach though.